# Assign elements from different tags to array

Tags: jquery, arrays, tags

I've a list of checkboxes and for each checkbox I want to assign the class name (ie the region) from the label tag, and the value (ie the country) from the input tag, to make a pair in an array.  In other words I'd like the array to be:
`["Europe", "Albania"] ["Europe", "Belgium"] ["NAM", "Canada"] ["NAM", "Cuba"]`.  Currently I'm mapping region and country separately as they are in different tags, and then plan to join them, but I can't believe this is efficient and I think I've confused myself.  Does anyone know a better way?  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fruL2u9L/

```
<div id="CountryStore_prodn">

<label class="Europe"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN8a" value="Albania" />Albania</label>
<label class="Europe"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN58a" value="Belgium" />Belgium</label>
<label class="NAM"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN124a" value="Canada" />Canada</label>
<label class="NAM"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN192a" value="Cuba" />Cuba</label>

</div>
```

.

```
// Assign all Filter regions to array
Region = $('#CountryStore_prodn label').map(function() {
  return this;
}).get();

// Assign all Country regions to array
Country = $('#CountryStore_prodn input').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();

console.log(Region);    
console.log(Country);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options for doing functionally the same thing: in the first case, we simply process all the label elements and create a two-member array from that, which we add to a master array. In the second, we wait for the checkboxes to be changed, and we dynamically re-create the checked array from the input element list itself. Hope it helps!

```js
// Create an array for all checkbox els
var masterArr = [], checkedArr = [];

// We'll go through and append the pair to the master array.
$("label").each(function(){
  // create a temporary array.
  var arrayItem = [];
  // Add the two values we'll need.
  arrayItem.push($(this).prop("class"));
  arrayItem.push($(this).find("[type='checkbox']").val() );
  
  // Now, we'll add that two-item array to the master.
  masterArr.push(arrayItem);
  });
  console.log(masterArr);
  
// Another thing we can do, is to create an array of just
//  the checked items. In this, we're doing the same thing, 
//  but rather than reference the label, we'll be starting
//  from the checked checkboxes.
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {
  // Empty the checked array
  checkedArr = [];
  // process each checked box, and create a two-item array.
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    var arrayEl = [];
    arrayEl.push($(this).parent().prop("class"));
    arrayEl.push($(this).val())
    
    // Add that two-item array to the checkedArr
    checkedArr.push(arrayEl);
  });
  console.log(checkedArr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CountryStore_prodn">

<label class="Europe"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN8a" value="Albania" />Albania</label>
<label class="Europe"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN58a" value="Belgium" />Belgium</label>

<label class="NAM"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN124a" value="Canada" />Canada</label>
<label class="NAM"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN192a" value="Cuba" />Cuba</label>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow @Snowmonkey you made that look too easy and I understand all your explanations!  The first option is best for my needs, but the second will come in very useful later.  Your help very much appreciated.

Comment: glad I could help. Often, it's easy to get lost in complexities when a simple solution is right there. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [];
$('#CountryStore_prodn label').each(function() {
      arr.push([$(this).attr("class"),$("input",this).val()]);
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CountryStore_prodn">

<label class="Europe"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN8a" value="Albania" />Albania</label>
<label class="Europe"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN58a" value="Belgium" />Belgium</label>

<label class="NAM"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN124a" value="Canada" />Canada</label>
<label class="NAM"><input type="checkbox"  id="UN192a" value="Cuba" />Cuba</label>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey, that's a really efficient and useful solution too